# A little confused by this.... Initializes all the elements of a numeric array to o, assuming the size of the array is n using a algorithm

Tags: arrays, c, initialization

Write an algorithm That initializes all the elements of a numeric array to o, assuming the size of the array is n.

Comment: Sure. What language?

Comment: I have to use C programing

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   :
   :

int array[n];

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    array[i] = 0;

   :
   :
```

Comment: can you explain the 3rd line please ?

Comment: The first line, `int array[n];`, declared an array of integers with `n` elements. The second line initiates a `for` loop with an initial value of zero, and repeats the following statement for all values of `i` from 0 up to (but not including) `n`. The third line, `array[i] = 0;` sets the `i`th element of the array to zero.

Comment: ohhh ok ok thank you very much